# Correlated subquery in MS Access don't see variable from outer query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, correlated-subquery

I have several tables, besides others I want to also get how many children every parent has - for this purpose I use subquery, which itself works fine.
But inside rest of query I am getting `Invalid Argument to Function`. It seems to me, that `p.parent_number` is not passed from outer query to subquery (if I put some static value instead variable, entire query works fine).

Is there some kind of limitation?

```
SELECT
    p.parent_number,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Child c
        WHERE c.[Parent ID] = p.parent_number) as [Child sum],
    s.code
FROM Seat s
    RIGHT JOIN (Parent p LEFT JOIN Child c ON p.parent_number = c.[Parent ID]) ON s.id_stred = c.seat
ORDER BY p.parent_number;
```

Comment: What is **seat** table? `SELECT Parent.Parent_Number, Count(Child.ChildNumber) As TotalChildren FROM Parent INNER JOIN Child on Parent.Parent_Number = Child.Parent_Number` This should just give you the result you need (minus the Seat table), no need for SubQuery.

Comment: sorry for late reply; in this case I also have to use `group by`, right? But when I put all the columns used in select into group by statement, it won't work; seat table contains some other info I need to get into query, it's connected via Child table.